# H2 Database File Corrupted Error When Connecting From Application

Tags: scala, sbt, h2, doobie

I have a database file like this in my local folder:

```
Wed Sep 13 07:46:05 2023  cpo-platform-h2-test.db.mv.db
Wed Sep 13 07:46:44 2023  cpo-platform-h2-test.db.trace.db
```

Whenever I connect to this database from my application, I keep getting this error below:

```
 Request File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-200]
```

I even deleted the database file completely and created a totally new file by running my flyway migrations. But this error seems not to go away. I can connect to the database via the web browser that h2 provides.

Why am I facing this error only when I connect via my application. Is there a fix to shi?